# Block remote ssh login on desktop

Tags: networking, ssh

I use the `ssh` command to connect to remote servers from my desktop. On the other hand, I would like to disable incoming ssh connections to my own desktop for I use it only locally. I'm new to this, so it's not clear to me if I should take any steps to configure this security measures or if my desktop has incoming ssh logins disabled by default.

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. Besides the services and commands that came by default after installing Ubuntu, I haven't installed any other network related utility besides `ssh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed the ssh server than you may be accepting incoming SSH connections. However if you just installed the ssh client, than you are good to go. You need to be running a ssh server to allow incoming connections.

You can check if you have ssh-server running on your Ubuntu with

`sudo service --status-all | grep ssh` if there is a `[ + ] ssh` than you're running an ssh server, and you can disable ssh connections by turning off the ssh server with: `sudo service ssh stop`.

Comment: I verified I'm just using the ssh client. Thank you for your help.